# unable to drag dynamically created div (ckdDrag) in angular7

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular7

After dragging and dropping an element, based on x and y offset im appending a html code(div with cdkDrag).I want this newly added div to drag around on the same container.But cdkDrag is not working
for dynamically created elements

```
app.component.html
```

```
        <div #html_container> <div cdkDrag > Product 1 </div></div>
        <button (click) = "create_element()" > Add New </button>
```

```
app.component.ts
```

```
            construct(public render2: Renderer2) {}
            product_name:string='';
            @ViewChild('html_container') public html_container: ElementRef;

        create_element() {
            this.getProductName();
            const add_html = '<div cdkDrag >'+this.product_name+'</div>';
            const p = this.render2.createElement('html_container');
            p.innerHTML = add_html;
            this.render2.appendChild(this.html_container.nativeElement, p);
        }

        getProductName(){
            this.product_name = 'Product 2'; //this will be dynamic value comming from backend services
       }
```

The product names (this.product_name) are not in sequence. They generated randomly based on business logic from server side.

"Dynamically generated this.product_name (Product N)"
has to be draggble

Comment: Adding html tag div with attribute cdkDrag does not make it CdkDrag component.

Comment: Thanks for the response. And how can I achieve this ? @Dimanoid

Answer (score 1):

you cannot dynamically add cdkDrag to an element but you can achieve with a *ngFor
Example

```
///get data from array 
const items=['one','two'];

///use with ngFor so that if you push some data in to that array that will 
automatically get drag and drop option
<div *ngFor='let item of items'>
 <div cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```